# Cannot connect to MSSQL using PHP sqlsrv_connect

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv, dbeaver

PHP version 8.1, using ODBC driver 18

Trying to do it with

`$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);`

using the same credentials as in `DBeaver` client (which works fine)

The error I'm getting is:

```
[0] => 28000
[SQLSTATE] => 28000
[1] => 18456
[code] => 18456
[2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user'.
[message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user'
```

How can I debug it further?

Comment: Check the SQL Server's logs and get the true authentication error.If you don't understand that error, edit your question to include it in your question.

Comment: @Larnu I don't have access to SQL Server's logs at the moment

Comment: Then speak to someone that does. The authentication errors passed to the application layer are intentionally vague; they won't give you good information on why the authentication failed as that would make it easier for a malicious user to draw conclusions on why their attempts are failing.